# Show the user's annotation count in the flag queue

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, flag-queue, annotations

Often when dealing with flags, I don't bother to look at the user - it takes time, and most often doesn't yield any useful information. But when a user has been annotated by another moderator (or me, I tend to forget these things), it's usually for something *very important* that I should know about.

Can this information be *pushed* to be in the flag queue, instead of me having to pull it from the user profile?

We could add something like this to the user profile box on flags:

[image]

Where the `[1]` links directly the the user's history page.

Thoughts?